# python - how do i assign columns to my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 lists that I need to put into a dataframe. The first list has the variable names and the second has the values. I'm using pandas to assign the column names. How do I go about assigning the actual values?

```
varnames = ['Student_id','First_Name','Last_Name','Grade']
values = [['156841','Mark','Smith','85'],
          ['785496','Jason','Gross','90'],
          ['785612','Laura','Clarkson','76'],
          ['125465','Tria','Carr','100']]

data1 = pandas.DataFrame(columns = varnames)
print(data1)
```

I've tried using append but I get the following error: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(values, columns=varnames)`

Comment: If you search in your browser for "PANDAS create column", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the `columns` argument in [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with the `data` argument; the doc tells you this:

- **`columns` argument is only for the list of column names**
- `data` argument is for their values, optionally as a dict with also column names as the keys. That's what you're trying to pass in:

  `data1 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'Student_id': ['156841','785496'...], 'First_Name': ['Mark','Jason'...]})`

or in your case:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=values, columns=varnames) @ as @AndyL noted
```

You can get the same thing with the convoluted syntax:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=dict(zip(varnames, values)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

varnames = ['Student_id','First_Name','Last_Name','Grade']
values = [['156841','Mark','Smith','85'],
         ['785496','Jason','Gross','90'],
         ['785612','Laura','Clarkson','76'],
         ['125465','Tria','Carr','100']]

data1 = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=varnames)
data1
```